# I need help finding this kanji

Tags: kanji

[image]

It looks something like this, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Why don't you try a handwriting recognition tool like this one: https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/66620963_2348018348639368_1703373120376668160_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_eui2=AeGSpOv3uGgRMt-yaxQ6U1eLwXiF2yoCVItLNkdq8rzr7MySYQ704db321oxTvDcnxTHmnERIOyBCb48BBGHCXsM2zPoWtrrRDXYdzlWXS6pyQ&_nc_oc=AQmQV7Dy1MECT_VPkUo0vCzMMuaxO3Z_RbqDDHTvuud8BvPeAW6YrjbTJmRQJQIKwiHTGWfG2QkO-sPjzq9uMTJ9&_nc_ht=scontent-nrt1-1.xx&oh=17c4c603041d05f46ad7beb6fe044a3a&oe=5DC4AAE6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is 爆 (ばく) meaning ‘bomb’ or ‘pop’ or ‘split’ or similar in kanji-compounds, or is also sometimes used for a ‘roar of laughter’?

In your drawing, it seems you have, instead of writing 龷 and *then* 丿and 乀 underneath, you have combined the vertical strokes in the sloping ones beneath: I think this might be the reason why you have had trouble finding it in a handwriting recognition dictionary, or a dictionary that goes on stroke count.